# batch file to replace "=" to "?" in files or variables

Tags: file, batch-file, replace, equals

I want batch file to replace this symbol "=" with this symbol "?" in files or variables

For example:

```
@echo off

set file="=test.exe"

set name2=%file:==?%

ren %file% %name2%
```

(((if you give my code for variables it will be better)))

Comment: Using a `?` in a Windows file name is never going to work. Windows does not allow the following characters in file names - `\/:*?"<>|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "junk=hello=this=is=the=original="
set "junk=q%junk%q"
:again
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ("%junk%") do if not "%%b"=="" set "junk=%%a?%%b"&goto again
set junk=%junk:~1,-1%
echo result:%junk%:
GOTO :EOF
```

Need to get sneakier if there are successive "=" though...

---

edited to suit initial or terminal `=`

Comment: this code is work if the = not the first charachter i edited your code to be like this                                                                                        @echo off
SETLOCAL
set /p file=enter the name of file:
set "junk=%file%"
:again
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ("%junk%") do if not "%%b"=="" set "junk=%%a?%%b"&goto again
echo %junk% > 11.txt
pause                                                                (((can you edit this code to able to transfer the "=" to question mark "?" in the first of file ?? ??))

Answer (score 2):

There is extensive discussion about this and related issues at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1485. There are quite a few proposed solutions.

My [REPL.BAT utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) would seem like a great option, except there are potential problems when trying to capture the result back into an environment variable. FOR /F can be used, but it has issues with new line characters, as well as complications when the result includes `!` (and possibly `^`) characters and delayed expansion is enabled.

So I decided to write a variant of REPL.BAT called [REPLVAR.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5492) with the following features:

- Both the input and output values are passed by reference via variable names.
- Searches can be interpreted as regular expressions, or as string literals.
- Searches can be case sensitive or insensitive
- Replacement strings can reference matched content from the search.
- Many escape sequences are supported in both the search and target strings: All possible byte codes are supported.
- The utility can be safely called with delayed expansion enabled or disabled, and all input and output characters will be preserved.

Note - The utility is intended for extended ASCII values. The variable should contain a value that maps to the active code page. Also, the final output must be compatible with the active code page, otherwise an error is raised.

The utility is pure script that is a hybrid of JScript and batch. It should work on any modern Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

Here is a trivial example of usage:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "input=1 + 1 = 3!"
call replVar input output "=" "<>" L
echo(!output!
```

--OUTPUT--

```
1 + 1 <> 3!
```

I originally posted the code at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5492, but I am including it here as well:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Documentation ***********
::REPLVAR.BAT version 1.4
:::
:::REPLVAR  InVar  OutVar  Search  Replace  [Options]
:::REPLVAR  /?[REGEX|REPLACE]
:::REPLVAR  /V
:::
:::  Performs a global regular expression search and replace on the contents of
:::  variable InVar and writes the result to variable OutVar.
:::
:::  REPLVAR.BAT works properly with delayed expansion enabled or disabled.
:::
:::  REPLVAR.BAT treats the source variable value as extended ASCII. The value
:::  should map properly to the active code page. Unicode source values that
:::  do not map to the active code page will be silently transformed to a new
:::  value that does map to the active code page. The result of the search and
:::  replace must be compatible with the active code page, otherwise an error
:::  is raised.
:::
:::  The maximum supported output string length usually approaches the 8191
:::  maximum for most strings. But it could be significantly less if the output
:::  string contains many % " \r or \n characters, as they must be temporarily
:::  expanded into 2 or 3 bytes. Also, ^ and ! characters are temporarily
:::  expanded into 2 bytes if delayed expansion is enabled.
:::
:::  REPLVAR.BAT returns with ERRORLEVEL 0 upon success, and ERRORLEVEL 1
:::  upon error. If the A option is used and the input was not altered then
:::  OutVar is undefined and ERRORLEVEL set to 2.
:::
:::  Each parameter may be optionally enclosed by double quotes. The double
:::  quotes are not considered part of the argument. The quotes are required
:::  if the parameter contains a batch token delimiter like space, tab, comma,
:::  semicolon. The quotes should also be used if the argument contains a
:::  batch special character like &, |, etc. so that the special character
:::  does not need to be escaped with ^.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /?, then prints help documentation
:::  to stdout. If a single argument of /?REGEX, then opens up Microsoft's
:::  JScript regular expression documentation within your browser. If a single
:::  argument of /?REPLACE, then opens up Microsoft's JScript REPLACE
:::  documentation within your browser.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /V, case insensitive, then prints
:::  the version of REPLVAR.BAT.
:::
:::  InVar   - The name of a variable containing the source string.
:::
:::  OutVar  - The name of a variable where the result should be stored.
:::
:::  Search  - By default, this is a case sensitive JScript (ECMA) regular
:::            expression expressed as a string.
:::
:::            The search is conducted using the regular expression g (global)
:::            and m (multilline) flags.
:::
:::            JScript regex syntax documentation is available at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Replace - By default, this is the string to be used as a replacement for
:::            each found search expression. Full support is provided for
:::            substituion patterns available to the JScript replace method.
:::
:::            For example, $& represents the portion of the source that matched
:::            the entire search pattern, $1 represents the first captured
:::            submatch, $2 the second captured submatch, etc. A $ literal
:::            can be escaped as $$.
:::
:::            An empty replacement string must be represented as "".
:::
:::            Replace substitution pattern syntax is fully documented at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Options - An optional string of characters used to alter the behavior
:::            of REPLVAR. The option characters are case insensitive, and may
:::            appear in any order.
:::
:::            I - Makes the search case-insensitive.
:::
:::            L - The Search is treated as a string literal instead of a
:::                regular expression. Also, all $ found in Replace are
:::                treated as $ literals.
:::
:::            B - The Search must match the beginning of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            E - The Search must match the end of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            A - Only return a value if the input was altered. If not altered,
:::                then ERRORLEVEL is set to 2.
:::
:::            X - Enables extended substitution pattern syntax with support
:::                for the following escape sequences within the Replace string:
:::
:::                \\     -  Backslash
:::                \b     -  Backspace
:::                \f     -  Formfeed
:::                \n     -  Newline
:::                \q     -  Quote
:::                \r     -  Carriage Return
:::                \t     -  Horizontal Tab
:::                \v     -  Vertical Tab
:::                \xnn   -  Extended ASCII byte code expressed as 2 hex digits
:::                \unnnn -  Unicode character expressed as 4 hex digits
:::
:::                Also enables the \q escape sequence for the Search string.
:::                The other escape sequences are already standard for a regular
:::                expression Search string.
:::
:::                Also modifies the behavior of \xnn in the Search string to work
:::                properly with extended ASCII byte codes.
:::
:::                Extended escape sequences are supported even when the L option
:::                is used. Both Search and Replace support all of the extended
:::                escape sequences if both the X and L opions are combined.
:::
::: REPLVAR.BAT was written by Dave Benham, with assistance from DosTips users
::: Aacini and Liviu regarding complications due to JScript's use of unicode vs.
::: cmd.exe's use of extended ASCII. REPLVAR.BAT also uses a modifed form of the
::: safe return technique developed by DosTips user jeb. Updates to REPLVAR.BAT
::: will be posted to the original posting site:
::: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5492
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********

@echo off
if .%4 equ . (
  if "%~1" equ "/?" (
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /n "^:::" "%~f0"') do echo(%%B
    exit /b 0
  ) else if /i "%~1" equ "/?REGEX" (
    start "" "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx"
    exit /b 0
  ) else if /i "%~1" equ "/?REPLACE" (
    start "" "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx"
    exit /b 0
  ) else if /i "%~1" equ "/V" (
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /nblc:"::REPLVAR.BAT version" "%~f0"') do echo(%%B
    exit /b 0
  ) else (
    call :err "Insufficient arguments"
    exit /b 1
  )
)
echo(%~5|findstr /i "[^ILEBXA]" >nul && (
  call :err "Invalid option(s)"
  exit /b 1
)

setlocal
set "$replVar.notDelayed=!!"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims==" %%V in ('set ~ 2^>nul') do set "%%V="
set "~=!%~1!"
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "rtn="
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (
  'set ~ 2^>nul^|cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%$replVar.notDelayed%" %3 %4 %5'
) do set "rtn=%%A"
if defined rtn (
  set "err=%rtn:~0,1%"
  set "rtn=%rtn:~1%"
) else set "err=2"
if %err% equ 1 (echo ERROR: Result not compatible with active code page) >&2
if %err% equ 2 (echo Input not altered) >&2
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set ^"LF=^

^"
for /f %%A in ('copy /z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%A"
set "replace=%% """ !CR!!CR!"
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%J in ("!replace!") do for %%M in ("!LF!") do (
  endlocal
  endlocal
  endlocal
  endlocal
  set "%~2=%rtn%" !
  exit /b %err%
)

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use replVar /? to get help.
exit /b


************* JScript portion **********/
var env=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var search=args.Item(1);
var replace=args.Item(2);
var options="gm";
if (args.length>3) options+=args.Item(3).toLowerCase();
var alterations=(options.indexOf("a")>=0);
if (alterations) options=options.replace(/a/g,"");
if (options.indexOf("x")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/x/g,"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\q/g,"\"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x80/g,"\\u20AC");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x82/g,"\\u201A");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x83/g,"\\u0192");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x84/g,"\\u201E");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x85/g,"\\u2026");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x86/g,"\\u2020");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x87/g,"\\u2021");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x88/g,"\\u02C6");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x89/g,"\\u2030");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[aA]/g,"\\u0160");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[bB]/g,"\\u2039");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[cC]/g,"\\u0152");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[eE]/g,"\\u017D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x91/g,"\\u2018");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x92/g,"\\u2019");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x93/g,"\\u201C");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x94/g,"\\u201D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x95/g,"\\u2022");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x96/g,"\\u2013");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x97/g,"\\u2014");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x98/g,"\\u02DC");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x99/g,"\\u2122");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[aA]/g,"\\u0161");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[bB]/g,"\\u203A");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[cC]/g,"\\u0153");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[dD]/g,"\\u009D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[eE]/g,"\\u017E");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[fF]/g,"\\u0178");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
    function($0,$1,$2){
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
    }
  );
  replace=replace.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
  search=search.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  search=search.replace(/\\q/g,"\"");
  search=search.replace(/\\x80/g,"\\u20AC");
  search=search.replace(/\\x82/g,"\\u201A");
  search=search.replace(/\\x83/g,"\\u0192");
  search=search.replace(/\\x84/g,"\\u201E");
  search=search.replace(/\\x85/g,"\\u2026");
  search=search.replace(/\\x86/g,"\\u2020");
  search=search.replace(/\\x87/g,"\\u2021");
  search=search.replace(/\\x88/g,"\\u02C6");
  search=search.replace(/\\x89/g,"\\u2030");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[aA]/g,"\\u0160");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[bB]/g,"\\u2039");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[cC]/g,"\\u0152");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[eE]/g,"\\u017D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x91/g,"\\u2018");
  search=search.replace(/\\x92/g,"\\u2019");
  search=search.replace(/\\x93/g,"\\u201C");
  search=search.replace(/\\x94/g,"\\u201D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x95/g,"\\u2022");
  search=search.replace(/\\x96/g,"\\u2013");
  search=search.replace(/\\x97/g,"\\u2014");
  search=search.replace(/\\x98/g,"\\u02DC");
  search=search.replace(/\\x99/g,"\\u2122");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[aA]/g,"\\u0161");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[bB]/g,"\\u203A");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[cC]/g,"\\u0153");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[dD]/g,"\\u009D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[eE]/g,"\\u017E");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[fF]/g,"\\u0178");
  if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
    search=search.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
    search=search.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
    search=search.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
    search=search.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
    search=search.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
    search=search.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
    search=search.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
      function($0,$1,$2){
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
      }
    );
    search=search.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
  } else search=search.replace(/\\B/g,"\\\\");
}
if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/l/g,"");
  search=search.replace(/([.^$*+?()[{\\|])/g,"\\$1");
  replace=replace.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$");
}
if (options.indexOf("b")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/b/g,"");
  search="^"+search
}
if (options.indexOf("e")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/e/g,"");
  search=search+"$"
}
var search=new RegExp(search,options);

var str1, str2, delay;
delay=args.Item(0);

if (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) str1=WScript.StdIn.ReadAll(); else str1="";
str1=str1.substr(2,str1.length-4);
str2=str1.replace(search,replace);
if (!alterations || str1!=str2) {
  str2=str2.replace(/%/g,"%J");
  str2=str2.replace(/\"/g,"%~K");
  str2=str2.replace(/\r/g,"%L");
  str2=str2.replace(/\n/g,"%~M");
  if (delay=="") {
    str2=str2.replace(/\^/g,"^^");
    str2=str2.replace(/!/g,"^!");
  }
  try {
    WScript.Stdout.Write("0"+str2);
  } catch (e) {
    WScript.Stdout.Write("1");
  }
}
```

Comment: EDIT - version 1.1: The code now detects if the final result is incompatible with the active code page, in which case the output is not set and ERRORLEVEL is set to 1. Also, all exit points now properly set the the ERRORLEVEL to 1 or 0.

Comment: EDIT - version 1.3: Fixed a bug with output when the input included extended ASCII values. Also dropped the V option, so the search and replace strings must now be passed as strings, never by reference using variable names.

Comment: EDIT - version 1.4: Fixed a bug with A opton. It became totally disfunctional with version 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
@echo off
set file="=test.exe"
set "name2=^"%file:~2%"
ren %file% %name2%
```

But, `ren` command seems not to work. Will it rename file `=test.exe` to `?test.exe` ?

Comment: You cannot use `?` in Windows file names.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why I asked.

Comment: this code edit the first charachter if it "=" it will replace it to ? but i need to search in all the sentence and transfer the "=" of these sentence to "?"

Comment: i dont want to rename files but if any one give the code of files i will transfer it to transfer the "=" to "?" in variable but i said it will be good to give my the code work with variables